# Broken bottom bracket spindle on spinning bike?

Tags: repair, bottom-bracket, replacement, indoor

So my spinning bike bottom bracket spindle (axle) broke.

Anyone know where can I find a replacement?

[image: ""]

[image]

Here is an
[image and video of broken part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVQKB.jpg)

Comment: Fwiw, I think you mean that the bottom bracket axle broke.

Comment: Oh I did not know that was the name for it. Thanks going to change the question.

Answer (score 2):

That is the bottom bracket axle and it has snapped.  You require a replacement axle.  To find out exactly what you need, both parts have to come out.   Try and avoid cutting or bending the parts, you might need accurate measurements off them later.

The crank arms require a "crank arm puller" to pull them off the axle.  
Then you need to undo the three bolts/screws on the belt pulley, to see what is holding that to the axle and to the frame.

On the broken side there appears to be a sealed ball bearing cartridge, which may slide off or may be pressed onto shaft with an inference fit (ie a tight press fit)

---

Sadly I think this is not a bicycle axle, this looks like a unique part for your brand of exercycle.  Contacting the supplier might be your only course of action.

The axle looks to be pressed into the belt pulley, and no conventional bike uses a V belt.  Strangely, most stationary bikes use a ribbed flat belt, a V belt is not at all typical here.

I would suspect that parts may be unobtainable, so you might need a machine shop to make you a new axle, or it may require complete replacement.  If that's the case, consider a normal bike, with an indoor trainer instead of a dedicated spinbike that can't be used to travel.